# Laravel - the requested url cannot be found on this server

Tags: apache, laravel, linode

I have deployed my project on `linode` and configured everything correctly but I find the homepage the only thing to be working. Anything else is giving me `The requested url can not be found on this server`. I have check all my configurations and everything seems to be correct. `a2enmod rewrite` is enabled and this `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /var/www/application
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

What else is missing?

Edit:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Comment: can you show me your file virtual host?

Comment: I have added the configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to set document root to the public folder of your application like so:

"var/www/your-site.com/public"

Comment: There is no public folder in the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try follow my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName yourproject.com
  ServerAlias www.yourproject.com

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/yourproject/public
  <Directory "/var/www/yourproject/public">
    Require all granted
    Allowoverride All
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: There is no public folder in the project structure.

Comment: I don't understand. This is a laravel project. Why no public folder?

Comment: It's based on hellovideoapp.com where I have an application folder and a content folder. The application folder contains everything except the public folder which is kind of weird

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `.htaccess` was missing so that was the reason. I have added it and it is working normally.